# Create Key_Shared Consumer Apache Pulsar

Tags: python, apache-pulsar, python-pulsar

I use the Apache Pulsar Python clients to connect my micro services. I want to create Key_Shared Consumer doing like:

```
import pulsar,_pulsar                

client = pulsar.Client('pulsar://localhost:6650')
consumer = client.subscribe('my-topic', 'consume-id',
             consumer_type=_pulsar.ConsumerType.KeyShared)
```

But I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'ConsumerType' has no attribute 'KeyShared'
```

Does the KeyShared has been implemented in the Python client ? If yes how can I use it ?

Answer (score 0):

It was released in 2.4.2 for the Python client.

Comment: Do you have code sample to show me how to use it ? I'm using the latest package